# Rewrite rule for subdomain and folders

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, subdomain

I need to write a rewrite rules for Apache to use with subdomains. The rules should be based on:

```
subdomain.domain.com => /home/domain/docs/some_folder/file.php?subdomain=subdomain
subdomain.domain.com/edit => /home/domain/docs/some_other_folder/file.php
subdomain.domain.com/dashboard/display/id => /home/domain/docs/some_other_folder2/file.php?param1=display&param2=id
```

I am also using AJAX calls on site which are not going to easily work, as I understood from searching the internet. So some hint on that will also really really helps.

I really appreciate your help!
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I'm gonna try with this

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^subdomain.domain.com$
RewriteRule .* - [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (.*)
RewriteRule ^$  /home/docs/some_folder/file.php?subdomain=%1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^edit$  /home/docs/some_other_folder/file.php [L]
RewriteRule ^dashboard/(\w+)/(\w+) /home/docs/some_other_folder2/file.php?param1=$1&param2=$2 [QSA,L]
```